# onclick in div not calling function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a problem where onclick in the code does not work, as the function does not run when clicking.

```
function kaka(x) {
   $('.' + x).each(function() {
      html += this.outerHTML;
   });
   $("#klasa").html(html);
   alert(html);
}

tab = ciong.split("&");
dlu = tab.length;
tab = removeDuplicates(tab);

for (var i = 0; i <= dlu; i++) {
   $("#linki").html($("#linki").html() + "<div onclick='kaka(\'" + tab[i] + "\');'> " + tab[i] + " </div>");
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).